# Best practise for Ajax Axios Javascript messengers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5, axios

So i am building a sort of messaging service on browsers using laravel with Laravel Passport and Axios to handle the API calls.

What I am trying to work out what is the best way for browsers to receive the data from the server using as little data as possible. All i can think of is requesting data every x amount of seconds.

I was wondering if anyone had an example or instruction on how to get the data efficiently.

I am not currently using vue js because I wanted to get everything working with jQuery instead.

Comment: what is efficiently  ... you are asking opinion ...

Comment: Ok efficiently maynot be the best way i have been saying. I am looking for a way to constantly connect to the database and get the data i need almost instantly like facebook messenger does on the browser or like twitter when getting new tweets with out overloading the users data/bandwidth. @VikingCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are 'event driven push messages'.

**Links to get you started**:

- `Socket.IO` enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication. - [socket.io](https://socket.io/)
- An implementation [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51) (walktrough) for `Laravel` with `Socket.IO`